# Export data from datagridview to MS Word table - error

Tags: c#, indexing, datagridview, ms-word, export

I try to get data from datagridview to MS word tables, but I get an error message: index is out of range. It must be non / negative .....
Can anyone help me, please?
Here is part of my code (I use using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word)

```
            Table thirdTable = document.Tables.Add(para3.Range,dataGridViewObjednavka.RowCount+1, dataGridViewObjednavka.ColumnCount, ref missing, ref missing);
            {
                //thirdTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Položka";
                //thirdTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Špecifikácia / materiál";
                //thirdTable.Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Objednávacie číslo";
                //thirdTable.Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Množstvo";
                {

                    int rowIndex = 0;
                    int colIndex = 0;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewObjednavka.Rows)
                    {
                        {
                            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridViewObjednavka.Columns)
                            {
                                thirdTable.Cell(rowIndex, colIndex).Range.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridViewObjednavka.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value);
                                colIndex++;
                            }
                            rowIndex++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Word, index is 1 based, not zero based. The smallest index for a row or column is 1. Also, `colIndex` needs to be re-initialized to 1 for each row. In the DataGridView the last row may be a new row and not contain any data. In the last row is an (empty) new row, skip it.

The following code takes data from a DataGridView and creates a Word document. In the Word document, three paragraphs are added. A table is created with the required number of rows and columns and the data is populated in the table. When finished, the word document is saved. The code below has been tested.

**Note**: If the filename that you specify already exists, it will throw an exception. You can change this behavior if you like.

**Add a module to your project**

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Module...** (name: HelperWord.vb)
- Click **Add**

**Helper.vb**

```
'Pre-requisite: MS Word installed
'
'Add Reference
'Project => Add Reference => COM => Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library (ex: Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library)
'
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewCell_FormattedValue

Imports System.IO
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Module HelperWord

    Public Sub CreateWordDocFromDataGridView(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal filename As String)

        Dim dgvUsableRowCount As Integer = 0
        Dim documents As Word.Documents = Nothing
        Dim doc As Word.Document = Nothing
        Dim errMsg As String = String.Empty
        Dim isVisible As Boolean = True 'Word visibility; if True, shows Word; if False, hides Word
        Dim oEndOfDoc = "\endofdoc" '\endofdoc is a predefined bookmark
        Dim oMissing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim para1 As Word.Paragraph = Nothing
        Dim para2 As Word.Paragraph = Nothing
        Dim para3 As Word.Paragraph = Nothing
        Dim para3Tbl As Word.Table = Nothing
        Dim wordApp As Word.Application = Nothing

        Try
            If File.Exists(filename) Then
                'if file already exists, throw an exception
                'this prevents an existing file from being overwritten
                Throw New Exception("File already exists (" & filename & ")")
            End If

            'last row of DataGridView may be a new row; if so, skip it as it doesn't contain any data
            'set the value of the last index in the DataGridView that we're interested in
            If dgv.Rows(dgv.Rows.Count - 1).IsNewRow Then
                'set value - ignore the last row in the DataGridView since it doesn't contain any data
                dgvUsableRowCount = dgv.Rows.Count - 1
            Else
                'set value - all DataGridView rows contain data
                dgvUsableRowCount = dgv.Rows.Count
            End If

            'if no data exists in the DataGridView, display message and return
            If dgvUsableRowCount <= 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("No data exists in the DataGridView", "No Data Exists", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Return
            End If

            'create new instance
            wordApp = New Word.Application()

            'suppress displaying alerts (such as prompting to overwrite existing file)
            wordApp.DisplayAlerts = False

            'set Word visibility
            wordApp.Visible = isVisible

            'create new document
            doc = wordApp.Documents.Add()
            doc.Activate()

            'create paragraphs
            para1 = doc.Paragraphs.Add() 'add paragraph
            para2 = doc.Paragraphs.Add() 'add paragraph
            para3 = doc.Paragraphs.Add() 'add paragraph

            'add table
            para3Tbl = doc.Tables.Add(para3.Range, dgvUsableRowCount, dgv.Columns.Count)

            'set table properties
            para3Tbl.BottomPadding = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.01F) 'use "f" for floating-point number
            para3Tbl.TopPadding = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.01F) 'use "f" for floating-point number
            para3Tbl.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle 'border between columns/rows
            para3Tbl.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle 'border around table

            'Debug.WriteLine("dgv row count: " & dgv.Rows.Count & " column count: " & dgv.Columns.Count)

            'since index starts at 0, the last index is count - 1
            For dgvRowIndex As Integer = 0 To dgvUsableRowCount - 1

                'DataGridView uses zero-based index
                'Word uses one-based index
                Dim wordRowIndex As Integer = dgvRowIndex + 1 'add 1

                'Debug.WriteLine("\n wordRowIndex: " & wordRowIndex)

                'since index starts at 0, the last index is count - 1
                For dgvColIndex As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
                    'DataGridView uses zero-based index
                    'Word uses one-based index
                    Dim wordColIndex As Integer = dgvColIndex + 1 'add 1

                    'Debug.WriteLine("wordColIndex: " & wordColIndex)

                    Dim value As String = String.Empty
                    If dgv.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
                        value = dgv.Rows(dgvRowIndex).Cells(dgvColIndex).GetEditedFormattedValue(dgvRowIndex, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Formatting).ToString()
                    Else
                        value = dgv.Rows(dgvRowIndex).Cells(dgvColIndex).FormattedValue.ToString()
                    End If

                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
                        'populate table cell
                        para3Tbl.Cell(wordRowIndex, wordColIndex).Range.Text = value
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) Then
                Try
                    'save document
                    'doc.SaveAs(filename, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing)
                    doc.SaveAs2(filename, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument, CompatibilityMode:=Word.WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2013)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    errMsg = "Error (CreateWordDocFromDataGridView) - " & ex.Message
                    Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
                    Throw ex 're-throw error
                End Try
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error () - " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        Finally
            If doc IsNot Nothing Then
                doc.Close()
                doc = Nothing
            End If

            If wordApp IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim oFalse As Object = False
                wordApp.Quit(oFalse, oFalse, oFalse)

                'release all resources
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordApp)

                wordApp = Nothing
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

**Usage**:

```
'write file to Documents folder (ex: C:\Users\<username>\Documents\TestWordDoc.docx)
Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "TestWordDoc.docx")
HelperWord.CreateWordDocFromDataGridView(dataGridViewObjednavka, filename)
```

**Resources**:

- [DataGridView Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word?view=word-pia)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to change the int values ​​to 1, but I still have a problem .... I really can't handle it

Comment: I've updated the post. `colIndex` needs to be re-initialized to 1 for each row.

Comment: Thanks again, but even after using your code, I still have an error message with the index. I'm a beginner and I only have it as a hobby. I really don't know where the mistake is

Comment: I've updated the code with a complete working solution. It's been tested. Feel free to modify it to fit your needs.